# My login scripts working fine on localserver but it not working on live server

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I am using my admin panel login script where i have created a global.php file with code including this:-

```
<?php

$Global['host']="localhost";
$Global['username']="username";
$Global['password']="*******";
$Global['database']="database_name";
$Global['baseurl']='www.somesite.com/work/';

$connhandle=mysql_connect($Global['host'],$Global['username'],$Global['password'])or  die('can\'t establish connection with mysql database');
$dbSelect=mysql_select_db($Global['database'],$connhandle) or die('could not connect to the database');
?>
```

and for calling the script on clock i m using a redirect.php file which include code as follows:-

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['pass'];
$_SESSION['aid'] = 0;

include 'global.php';

$admin_themes=mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("select * from admin where id='1'"));

$ruser = $admin_themes->username;
$rpass = $admin_themes->password;

if ($_SESSION['username'] == $ruser && $_SESSION['password'] == $rpass) {
$_SESSION['aid'] = 1;
header("location:../index.php");
}
else {
header("location:../admin_login.php?passcheck");
}
?>
```

no this scripts in working absolutely fine when i run this using my xampp server on local. but when i upload it to my online server the redirect script show me this error:-

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/..../public_html/work/h_cms/configuration/global.php on line 9
can't establish connection with mysql database

any suggestion why its not showing on online server i have used the correct username and pass of my database i have checked it 5 times. But still not find where is the problem.

Comment: Do you change your mysql connect parameters at server after upload ?

Comment: your database username , password and hostname is not correct. please check those and replace with true values.

Comment: ys i did that already. i have changed all username, pass, database name on global.php file

Comment: @safarov-  what parameters whould i change can u write here pls

Comment: Also remember to export your database to the live server when copying the files.  You must also create the user and password and give them permissions to the table.

Comment: finnaly i got solved, it was actually the user problem i have created a news user on my server and i was trying to access with that user, then later i tried with the older user then it allow me to logged in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

username@localhost is clearly not the correct username based on the error message. if you're subscribing to a hosting provider, you may want to check with them the correct username for your mysql account.

also, you might want to try using your domain name instead of localhost.

Comment: username is just for example i have used here the user name i have copied exactly same what i have created on my mysql database. but its not log me in. and also tried the domain name also instead of localhost that also didn't work

Comment: finnaly i got solved, it was actually the user problem i have created a news user on my server and i was trying to access with that user, then later i tried with the older user then it allow me to logged in :) . thanks for everyone's effort

Comment: as was said, it was a user issue. glad you got this solved. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your database username, password or hostname is not correct. You need to check what the correct details are and update your code accordingly.

Be aware afterwards you might need to create the necessary database and tables again so your app can run.